# Flush variables set through BusinessProcess

Tags: java, camunda

When I set a process variable through `org.camunda.bpm.engine.cdi.BusinessProcess.setVariable()` it seems the value is not automatically flushed.

Is there a way to flush the variables without completing the current user task? I thought `BusinessProcess.signalExecution()` would be the solution but it seems to complete the current task just as `BusinessProcess.completeTask()` does.

What exactly is the difference between `signalExecution` and `completeTask`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are cached in the Request or Conversation until the unit of work is ended, for example by calling `completeTask()`. There is currently no out-of-the-box solution for manually flushing the cached variables. You could work around this by writing a Cdi Bean which injects the ContextAssociationManager and performs the flush:

```
@Inject
private ContextAssociationManager contextAssociationManager;

@Inject 
private TaskService taskService;

public void flushCachedVariables() {
  String taskId = contextAssociationManager.getTask().getId();
  taskService.setVariables(taskId, contextAssociationManager.getCachedVariables());
}
```

The difference between `signalExecution` and `completeTask` is as follows:

- `completeTask`: will complete the currently associated task using the TaskService
- `signalExecution`: is more abstract: it sends a signal to the currently associated execution to continue execution. In this case the effect is the same: the task is completed and execution continue. But `signalExecution` will also work in situations where there is no Human Task involved (ie. a [ReceiveTask](http://docs.camunda.org/api-references/bpmn20/#!/tasks/receive-task)).